# Hide children element of a clicked element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a order form in a site. The  HTML is as follow.

```
 <table class="variations">
    <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-
    one-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-
    value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-
    value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-two-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-three-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
</table>
```

I am working in a logic like if some one click any of the span item the same span item in next block of division will be hidden.
If a use click again on it the hidden element must be visible.

This is a inside a T-Shirt order plugin, My aim is to prevent users selecting same color in each t-shirt model.
So far i did following code but it not working as expected. Can some one help me with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_t-shirt-one-color']").click(function(){
        function hidecolor() {
         var classes = ['swatch-green','swatch-red','swatch-yellow'];
         $('.' + classes.join(',.')).click(function(){
             var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
             var colorcls;
             $.each(classNames, function(i, c) {
                 if( $.inArray(c, classes) !== -1 ) {
                     colorcls = c;
                     return false;

                 }
             });
                 var fclass = '.'+colorcls;
             //alert(fclass);
                 //$(fclass).hide();

                 $two = $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_t-shirt-two-color']")
                 $three = $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_t-shirt-three-color']")
                 $two.find(fclass).hide();
                 $three.find(fclass).hide();

         });
         }
    hidecolor();
    });
```

Comment: `table`should have `tr` children and not `div`

Comment: yes its is there. I did't paste entire form code here.

Comment: Defining a click handler within a click handler is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: use a change event on the select. Using click is a bad idea.

Comment: I don't understand why the outer click handler defines `hidecolor` as a named function, and then calls it.  No where else is that used.

Comment: I made it more complicated any simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.variations').on('click', '.swatch-color', function(){
  var $theSwatchClicked = $(this);
  var $swatchesWithTheSameColor = $('.variations').find('.swatch-'+ $theSwatchClicked.data('value'));

  if ($theSwatchClicked.is('.selected')) {
    $theSwatchClicked.removeClass('selected');
    $swatchesWithTheSameColor.removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $theSwatchClicked.addClass('selected')
    $swatchesWithTheSameColor.not('.selected').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variations">
  <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-
    one-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-two-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-three-color">
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this code is working almost. But while we click some more time with different selection. Its removing the 3rd selection completely. And some time it working reverse after some attempt.

Comment: Should you be able to only select one color per tawcvs-swatches group?

Comment: Yes. User able to select one color in on group. If they select a color they are not able to select same. See the frond-end https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/3n3j1y3T3g3M0w2Z272C/Image%202018-03-01%20at%2010.22.52%20PM.public.png

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid: `table` tags cannot have `div` as children, so I added some `tr` and `td` tags to make it valid.

It is almost always a bad idea to define an event handler within an event handler.

One idea to get your desired effect is to detect in which row your click happens. This can be done with `$(this).closest(".tawcvs-swatches").index()`. It returns 0, 1 or 2.

Then you could get all the elements of the same color. That you could get with `$(".swatch-" + $(this).data('value'))`, provided that you also add the `data-value` for the yellow `span` elements.

With those two pieces of information you can slice the elements that are *below* the current element. Finally `toggle` will switch between visible and not visible.

The following code implements this idea:

```js
$('.variations .tawcvs-swatches .swatch').click(function () {
    var $match = $(".variations .tawcvs-swatches .swatch-" + $(this).data('value'))
        .slice($(this).closest(".tawcvs-swatches").index()+1);

    $match.toggle(!$match.is(':visible'));
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="variations">
    <tr class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-one-color">
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-two-color">
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_t-shirt-three-color">
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-green" data-value="green">Green</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-red " data-value="red">Red</span></td>
        <td><span class="swatch swatch-color swatch-yellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```